# How to extract piece of string within string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Log from which I want to extract anything after "name=    ". Log looks like this:

```
BC_WVM_FAIL: Rend wrong size for BCID 4608603 rend_id: 4608621 expected sz: 220459951 actual sz: 90816512 name: The Real Housewives Of Orange County - S10 Ep2
```

Comment: I will assume you mean "name:", so `=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("name:",A1)-4))` If you really mean "name=" then change the "name:" to "name="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few options here. Both center around using either the [FIND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FIND-function-06213F91-B5BE-4544-8B0B-2FD5A775436F) (case-sensitive) or the 
[SEARCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-function-F79EF0B8-0991-4FC1-93B0-627F019A69E3) (non-case-sensitive) for locating the starting position of what to splice out of the longer text string.

```
=REPLACE(A1, 1, SEARCH("name:", A1)+LEN("name:"), "")
=MID(A1, SEARCH("name: ", A1)+LEN("name: "), 99999)
```